# XSLT for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a very tricky XSLT question.
Imagine I have the following input:

```
<OtherCharges>        
<LineId>
    <Id>P</Id>
</LineId>
<Items>
    <Item1>1</Item1>
    <Item2>2</Item2>
    <Item3>3</Item3>  
</Items>    
<LineId>
    <Id>P</Id>
</LineId>
<Items>
    <Item1>4</Item1>
</Items>
<LineId>
    <Id>P</Id>
</LineId>
<Items>
    <Item1>5</Item1>
    <Item2>6</Item2>    
</Items>
</OtherCharges>
```

and as an output I would like to have this:

```
<OtherCharges>
  <LineId>P</LineId>
  <OtherChargesValues>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>2</value>
    <value>3</value>
  </OtherChargesValues>
</OtherCharges>
<OtherCharges> 
  <LineId>P</LineId>
  <OtherChargesValues>
    <value>4</value>
  </OtherChargesValues>
</OtherCharges>
<OtherCharges> 
  <LineId>P</LineId>
  <OtherChargesValues>
    <value>5</value>
    <value>6</value>
  </OtherChargesValues>
</OtherCharges>
```

Where I can have an unlimited number of lines but each line has maximum of 3 items.
I've tried the following code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/OtherCharges/LineId">
<Id>
    <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
<Id>
<xsl:variable name="ChargeLine" select="."/>
<xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::Items[preceding-sibling::LineId[1] = $ChargeLine]">    
    <xsl:if test="name(.)='Items'">
        <xsl:if test="Item1">
            <value>
                <xsl:value-of select="Item1"/>
            </value>
        </xsl:if>  
        <xsl:if test="Item2">
            <value>
                <xsl:value-of select="Item2"/>
            </value>
        </xsl:if> 
        <xsl:if test="Item3">
            <value>
                <xsl:value-of select="Item3"/>
            </value>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If the ID's are different it works well but the problem is when I have the same ID values (as is in the example).
Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: NOTE: Thanks for the answers but the output was wrong. I'm very sorry about this. Indeed it seems it might have a simple solution but I'm not very experienced with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="*[not(self::LineId)]"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::LineId[1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="LineId">
  <OtherCharges>
     <LineId><xsl:value-of select="."/></LineId>
     <OtherChargesValues>
       <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup"
            select="key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
     </OtherChargesValues>
  </OtherCharges>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Items/*" mode="inGroup">
  <value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<OtherCharges>
    <LineId>
        <Id>P</Id>
    </LineId>
    <Items>
        <Item1>1</Item1>
        <Item2>2</Item2>
        <Item3>3</Item3>
    </Items>
    <LineId>
        <Id>P</Id>
    </LineId>
    <Items>
        <Item1>4</Item1>
    </Items>
    <LineId>
        <Id>P</Id>
    </LineId>
    <Items>
        <Item1>5</Item1>
        <Item2>6</Item2>
    </Items>
</OtherCharges>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<OtherCharges>
   <LineId>P</LineId>
   <OtherChargesValues>
      <value>1</value>
      <value>2</value>
      <value>3</value>
   </OtherChargesValues>
</OtherCharges>
<OtherCharges>
   <LineId>P</LineId>
   <OtherChargesValues>
      <value>4</value>
   </OtherChargesValues>
</OtherCharges>
<OtherCharges>
   <LineId>P</LineId>
   <OtherChargesValues>
      <value>5</value>
      <value>6</value>
   </OtherChargesValues>
</OtherCharges>
```

Comment: That works great! I actually didn't know about generate-id(). Thank you.

Comment: '...is the only way to test for node identity in XSLT 1.0'

Comment: @user295744, You are welcome. generate-id() is the only way to test for node identity in XSLT 1.0. In XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0) there is the is operator whose only semantics is to confirm identity between two nodes. –

Comment: @MiMo, Thanks for noticing this. The typo in the comment is now fixed.

Comment: @user295744, Actually there is at least one other way for checking for node identity in XPath 1.0: `count($n1|$n2) = 1`

Answer (score 1):

In general, avoid usng value-of and learn about apply-templates, and this will become a really easy XSLT question. Your output is not well-formed XML by the way, as it doesn't have a single root wrapper element.

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="OtherCharges" />

<xsl:template match="OtherCharges">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OtherCharges/LineId">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OtherCharges/Items">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<!--* now the real work *-->
<xsl:template match="OtherCharges/LineId/Id">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OtherCharges/Items/*">
  <value><xsl:apply-templates/></value>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the output was wrong. I'm very sorry about this. I've edited the output.

Answer (score 1):

`starts-with()` may help...

**XML Input**

```
<OtherCharges>        
    <LineId>
        <Id>P</Id>
    </LineId>
    <Items>
        <Item1>1</Item1>
        <Item2>2</Item2>
        <Item3>3</Item3>  
    </Items>    
    <LineId>
        <Id>P</Id>
    </LineId>
    <Items>
        <Item1>4</Item1>
    </Items>
    <LineId>
        <Id>P</Id>
    </LineId>
    <Items>
        <Item1>5</Item1>
        <Item2>6</Item2>    
    </Items>
</OtherCharges>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="Id">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Items/*[starts-with(name(),'Item')]">
        <value>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </value>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output** (not well-formed)

```
<Id>P</Id>
<value>1</value>
<value>2</value>
<value>3</value>
<Id>P</Id>
<value>4</value>
<Id>P</Id>
<value>5</value>
<value>6</value>
```

Comment: It does not produce the output requested in the question: the elements should be called `value`, not `Item1`, `Item2` etc.

Comment: @MiMo - I did not notice that. Nice catch. I will try to update when I have a minute. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the output was wrong. I'm very sorry about this. I've edited the output.